# How to get the binded Item from a listbox when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a `ListBox` control which contains a number of items (these are UserControls), the `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. All that part works well, the ListBox shows each item in the collection as desired.

However, I would like to place a "remove" button next to each user control so that when the user clicks the button, that item is removed from the list. After some research, and a few attempts at solving this issue myself, I have currently got the following code:

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <c:MyControl Text="{Binding Path=ItemText}" />
                <c:CustomButton Text="Remove" Click="RemoveButton_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

.CS:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }

private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as CustomButton;
    var item = button.DataContext as MyItem;
    MyItems.Remove(item);
}
```

The problem I am having is that `item` is null, and the reason for this is because `button.DataContext` is of type `CustomButton`, where as I was expecting it to be of type `MyItem`.

What am I missing so that the buttons `DataContext` will be the correct `MyItem` object? Or is there something else I can use to get the bound item from within the click event? What reason would cause the `DataContext` to reference itself?

Comment: Your CustomButton is setting it's DataContext to itself, which is wrong. Remove that.

Comment: @HighCore: Well done, that fixed it, and you didn't even have to see my `CustomButton` xaml. I had that in there because I am binding within the `CustomButton` to various properties. However, I did that a  while back and have since learned how to use `Name` for self binding, so I could easily fix the problem. Consider posting an answer, and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the OP's request:

Your CustomButton is setting it's DataContext to itself, either in XAML:

```
<Button x:Class="My.CustomButton"
        ...
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   <!-- ... -->
</Button>
```

or in code:

```
public CustomButton()
{
   DataContext = this;
}
```

which is wrong. Remove that.

Comment: nice +1 for the way you have found it